# Redshift: Use Rank with condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to add a rank number for only delivered carts. I tried the below code but not getting the expected results.

Can we do this in a single query or we need to write a subquery for delivered carts & generate a rank. Please suggest here

Data:

| customer_id | cart_id | cart_current_status | ***rank*** | ***delivered_rank*** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | DELIVERED | ***1*** | ***1*** |
| 1 | 110 | CANCELLED | ***2*** | ***NULL*** |
| 1 | 220 | DELIVERED | ***3*** | ***2*** |

Expected result: rank & delivered_rank Should be populated

Database: Amazon Redshift

```
select customer_id,cart_id,cart_current_status,
 dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
    ORDER BY
        cart_id ) AS cart_rank_asc,

  (sum(case when cart_current_status = 'DELIVERED' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer_id order by cart_id rows unbounded preceding)
     ) as delivered_cart_rank      

from sales_details
```

Comment: Please make this a complete question by adding sample data.

Comment: With some example source data we can see what scenarios you are and are not dealing with, then you can also provide example results that you would expect from that example source data.  This allows us to validate our understanding, and demonstrate that any answer generates the results you expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Added Sample Data

Answer (score 2):

I would adapt you query in two ways...

1. Add the `cart_current_status` to the `PARTITION BY`

This will mean that all `delivered` carts get their own rankings, and that all `cancelled` carts get their own rankings.

2. Wrap that ranking in a `CASE` expression to include only the rankings for `delivered` carts

This will turn the ranking for `cancelled` carts to `NULL`

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    cart_id,
    current_status,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY cart_id) AS cart_rank_asc,
    CASE
      WHEN cart_current_status = 'DELIVERED'
      THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, cart_current_status ORDER BY cart_id)
    END
      AS delivered_rank
FROM
    sales_details
ORDER BY
    customer_id,
    cart_id;
```

Note: Based on your data and explanation, `COUNT(*)`, `SUM(1)`, `DENSE_RANK()`, etc, will all give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `COUNT` here as an analytic function along with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    customer_id,
    cart_id,
    current_status,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY cart_id) cart_rank_asc,
    CASE WHEN current_status = 'DELIVERED'
         THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN current_status = 'DELIVERED' THEN 1 END) OVER
              (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY cart_id) END delivered_rank
FROM sales_details
ORDER BY
    customer_id,
    cart_id;
```

The `CASE` expression used above will render `NULL` for any record which is not a status delivered record.  Otherwise, it will show the rolling count of delivered records, for each block of customer records.